# Rotation of a point around an axis using the cartesian coordinates

Tags: trigonometry, 3d, coordinate-systems, rotations

I'm looking for the formula to calculate the cartesian coordinates of a point A(Xa, Ya, Za) after a rotation of an angle δ (in radians) around an axis B(Xb, Yb, Zb)C(Xc, Yc, Zc).

I found how to do it using [rotation matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) or [quaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation).
But how can I do that using the cartesian coordinates of the A, B and C points?

Comment: Roughly speaking, you just multiply the vector of point coordinates by the rotation matrix. You have to worry about details like pre vs post multiplying, and rows vs columns, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}$Here is an algorithm (not a formula *per se*, but can be turned into one):

1. Calculate the unit vector $\Vec{e}_{3} := \dfrac{C - B}{\|C - B\|}$.
2. Pick (or calculate) a unit vector $\Vec{e}_{1}$ perpendicular to $\Vec{e}_{3}$. (There is no continuous way to do this using $\Vec{e}_{3}$, but see note below.)
3. Put $\Vec{e}_{2} = \Vec{e}_{3} \times \Vec{e}_{1}$ and
   \begin{align*}
     \Vec{e}_{1}' &= \phantom{-}(\cos\delta) \Vec{e}_{1} + (\sin\delta) \Vec{e}_{2}, \\
     \Vec{e}_{2}' &= -(\sin\delta) \Vec{e}_{1} + (\cos\delta) \Vec{e}_{2}.
   \end{align*}
4. Let $v = A - B$. The desired point is
   $$
   A' = B + (v \cdot \Vec{e}_{1})\Vec{e}_{1}' + (v \cdot \Vec{e}_{2})\Vec{e}_{2}' + (v \cdot \Vec{e}_{3})\Vec{e}_{3}.
   $$

Geometrically, $(\Vec{e}_{1}', \Vec{e}_{2}', \Vec{e}_{3})$ is the result of rotating the "original" orthonormal basis $(\Vec{e}_{1}, \Vec{e}_{2}, \Vec{e}_{3})$ through angle $\delta$ about $\Vec{e}_{3}$. The formula in item 4. decomposes $A - B$ (the displacement of point $A$ from the "origin" $B$) into components with respect to the original basis, and uses those as components with respect to the rotated basis.

[image: Rotating a vector about an axis in three-space]

Note: If $\Vec{e}_{3} = (0, 0, \pm 1)$ we can pick $\Vec{e}_{1} = (1, 0, 0)$ and $\Vec{e}_{2} = (0, 1, 0)$. Otherwise, we have $\Vec{e}_{3} = (X, Y, Z)$ with $X^{2} + Y^{2} \neq 0$, and may pick
$$
\Vec{e}_{1} = \frac{(-Y, X, 0)}{\sqrt{X^{2} + Y^{2}}}.
$$
This is not numerically robust if the segment $\overline{BC}$ is nearly parallel to the third Cartesian axis. In practice, find the two largest (in absolute value) components of $\Vec{e}_{3}$ and pick $\Vec{e}_{1}$ using those instead of the first two.

Comment: Hi @Andrew D. Hwang, I was wondering if you could please help out with this question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4393300/585488 thanks.